# How to return multiple relationships with Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table called `users`. Each of these users has different things:

- country
- device
- computer
- category

I have created a table for each of these above 'things'. Similar the following:

```
1 | United States
2 | United Kingdom
3 | Australia
4 | Canada
5 | Italy
```

etc...

I'm storing these values in the users table as follows:

```
ID | Country | Device | Computer | Category |
---|---------|--------|----------|----------|
1  |       3 |      2 |        6 |        2 |
2  |       4 |      3 |        9 |        1 |
```

etc...

Now each of the above numbers are associated with the corresponding table's ID.

What I want is do an Eloquent Query and search for all the `users` and 'replacing' their corresponding values from their helper table.

I was thinking about doing a `hasOne()` Eloquent relationship for each of those things in the `users` table, but then I'm not sure how to get/call them at once.

Anyone can help me tacke this issue?

Comment: I find it hard to believe you're using laravel versions 4, 5, and 5.2 at the same time

Comment: Please fix your tags to the appropriate version of Laravel you are using.

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry for the confusion, done.

Comment: Is a user only ever going to have one device, one computer, and one category or can they have multiple at any point?

Comment: @AndrewNolan Right now they can only get 1 of those. I have successfully setup the many to many relationships already with pivot tables but I can't get my head around this one.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
$model = Model::with('relatedModel', 'relatedModelTwo')->get();
```

So in your case, it can be something like this. If you only want one relations returned with the `user`, remove the others.

```
$user = User::with('country', 'Device', 'Computer', 'Category')->get();
```

When you `dd($user)`, you should see the related models in the `relations` array attribute.

To access the relations' properties from there, it is simply

`$user->device->deviceAttribute`

*Edit For Comment:*

Eloquent will assume the foreign key uses the Model name. So if your `user` table has the `id` column, it assumes there will be a column on `device` table called `user_id`. If you did this, then you are set and nothing should have to be done.

If you named your column to relate the models something else, you will need to pass that through as a second argument in the relation method.

```
public function device()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Device', 'foreign_key_here',);
}
```

Inversely, if you wanted to get the user the device belongs to, Eloquent will attempt to match the `user_id` column on the device table to the `id` column on the user table. As before, if you used a different column to related them, declare the foreign key as the second argument.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'foreign_key_here',);
}
```

[Laravel Doc One-To-One Relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: Thanks for your answer it pretty much convers everything. There's only one thing left. How should I make the relationships so I can retrieve the correct value for the ID of the attribute?

Comment: @Radical_Activity to make sure you get the appropriate device, computer, etc for the user?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Maybe with `hasMany`? On the device, computer, etc?

Comment: @Radical_Activity check the edit. Since you stated they will only have one, using a hasMany relation isn't used.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working perfecty. Thanks for taking the time to answer for these questions, I really appreciate it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this: `$books = App\Book::with('author', 'publisher')->get();`

[Check out the documentation for eager loading multiple relationships.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)