# Laravel get relation with another relation

Tags: php, laravel

**SellerController.php**

```
public function products()
    {
        $seller = Auth::user();
        $products = Seller::find($seller->id)->products; //return only products, I need to get category with this relation!!!
        return response()->json(['data' => $products], 200);
    }
```

This return seller's products.

**Seller.php**

```
public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Products', 'user');
    }
```

**Products.php**

```
function seller()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Seller', 'user');
    }

    function Category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Category','cat');
    }
```

Now I want to return category with products in seller controller, how can I do this?

Comment: You need to load the models with the relation - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return multiple relationships with Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544455/how-to-return-multiple-relationships-with-laravel-eloquent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `with` function

```
 $products = Seller::findOrFail($seller->id)->products()->with('Category')->get();
```